# Unity New Input Manager and Photon issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm working on a multiplayer game and I'm encountering a issue when 2 players are loading the same level using PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel().

**When I start the game alone, I can control my player and everything is fine. But when we are 2 players, Player A is controlling Player B and vice-versa.**

I check a lot of links on the internet these past few days, and I learned the concept of PhotonNetwork.IsMine which I thought would solve all of my problem but it seems to not working with me. Also, I'm using the new input system of Unity but I don't think the issue come from here.

Basically, what I'm doing is:

- Instantiate a player (this happened twice since I have 2 players) which have a PlayerManager
- Player Manager Get Instance of the local player and synchronize camera with the local player only if isMine = true
- CameraManager creates input manager if the script is linked to the local player by using isMine
- Link the main camera to this script when the gamemanager request it
- Update camera rotation only when isMine is true (second protection)

Here is a piece of my code:

GameManager.cs (Holding by a Scene Object, so it is initially instantiated for everyone with the scene)

```
void Start()
    {
            if(PlayerManager.LocalPlayerInstance == null)
            {
                //Get player's team
                string team = (string)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Team"];
                int indexPlayer = GetSpawnPosition();

                //Spawn player depending on its team and its index in the players pool
                if (team.Equals("Spy"))
                {
                    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(this.spyPrefab.name, SpySpawns[indexPlayer].position, SpySpawns[indexPlayer].rotation);
                }
                else if (team.Equals("Defender"))
                {
                    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(this.defenderPrefab.name, SpySpawns[indexPlayer].position, SpySpawns[indexPlayer].rotation);
                }
        }
    }
```

PlayerManager.cs (Holding by the player, so not initially instantiated with the scene)

```
void Awake()
    {
        //Keep track of the localPlayer to prevent instanciation when levels are synchronized
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            LocalPlayerInstance = gameObject;
        }

        //Don't destroy this gameobject so it can survives level synchronization
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //Get Manager of the camera of the player and attach to the local player
        CameraLookFPS cameraFPSManager = gameObject.GetComponent<CameraLookFPS>();
        if (cameraFPSManager != null)
        {
            //Ensure that we the local player is controlling its own camera
            if(photonView.IsMine == true)
            {
                cameraFPSManager.SynchronizeWithLocalPlayer();
            }
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("This player is missing the CameraLookFPS component");
    }
```

CameraManager.cs (Holding by the player, so not initially instantiated with the scene)

```
private void Start()
    {
        //Synchronize camera with local player on start for debug
        if(SynchronizeOnStart)
        {
            SynchronizeWithLocalPlayer();
        }

        //Bind input for controlling the camera
        BindingInput();
    }

private void BindingInput()
    {
        // Prevent control is connected to Photon and represent the localPlayer
        if (photonView.IsMine == false && PhotonNetwork.IsConnected == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get Components
            Input_Master = new InputMaster();

            //Enable
            Input_Master.Enable();

            //Input binding
            Input_Master.Player.Look.performed += context => MoveCamera(context);
            Input_Master.Player.Look.Enable();
        }
    }

public void SynchronizeWithLocalPlayer()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine == false && PhotonNetwork.IsConnected == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        Player_Camera = Camera.main.transform;
        isSynchronized = true;
    }
```

I tried to be clear enough, tell me if something is bad explained. I'll continue my research on my side and I'll keep you in touch if I find something.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my solution. It appears that I already read about it but I have failed when trying to solve it.
So, like a lot of people, it is a Camera issue.
What I did is:

- Create a game object holding the camera and put it as a child of the player gameobject
- Deactivate the game object holding the camera
- When instantiating the player, check if the player is the local player, using PhotonNetwork.IsMine. If yes, activate the gameobject holding the camera through script

If you have questions, send me a message!

Adrien